# TimeStamp in Google sheet are keeping updated everyday

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I've created the below script in Google sheets to make time stamp and it worked fine to reflect the date

```
function TIMESTAMP() {

var today = new Date();
var date = (today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate()+'- 
'+today.getFullYear();
 var dateTime = date
return dateTime;

}
```

and in the sheet where I want it to reflect :

```
=if(K2="Done",TIMESTAMP())
```

Then the main issue is that when I opened the sheet today it reflected today's date not yesterday in the cells that I used them in.

Tried creating a timestamp 
Tried using normally the today or now function but they did the same
Tried using shortcut CTRL +; but this should be done manually and I do not want this 
Tried to make the source as a Macro but did not know how to apply it in this IF statement  `=if(K2="Done",TIMESTAMP())`

I am expecting to find a solution for this issue as this is for a sheet for tasks and I`enter code here` am creating this to let the team select Done word from a list to reflect the date the made done in the cell beside it directly

Comment: Hi, you can't do this with formulas as they get recalculated. What you'll need is a onEdit script that is triggered when the value 'Done' is selected and puts a timestamp in the column you desire. If you need help with that, please share a copy of your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

### Create a script that will insert a timestamp automatically every time a cell is marked as done, rather than running the script manually.

This is how you can do it:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var column=e.range.getColumn();
//check if a cell content in column K was set to "Done"
if(column==11&&e.value=="Done"){
  var today = new Date();
  var date = (today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate()+'-'+today.getFullYear();
  var dateTime = date;
  var row=e.range.getRow();
  //specify the column of your choice
  var timeStampColumn=12;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(row, timeStampColumn).setValue(dateTime);
 }
}
```

Save the code and try to run it once to initiate the Authentification flow. You will receive the error message 
`TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined`
because an onEdit funciton with event objects cannot be run manually, but your code will run from then on automatically - each time an edit to column K will be made.

References:

- [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object))